# ADO NET Source/Destination components missing from SSIS Toolbox

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ado.net, visual-studio-2022

I created an Azure enabled SSIS project that targets SQL Server 2017. In this project I can create ADO.NET connection but when I move in to the data flow task I can't see ADO NET source/destination components in SSIS toolbox.

[image]

This is happening in project targetting SQL 2017. I confirmed this by creating new project that targets SQL 2022. However, as I changed the target version of that SSIS package to SQL 2017, ADO NET components disappeared.

**How can I get these components for SSIS projects targetting SQL 2017?**

I am using

- Visual Studio 2022 community (ver 17.6.4 latest)
- Integration Services Projects extension (ver 1.0.1)

Comment: This is a bug introduced in the latest update of SSIS extension or may be VS 2022 update. For more information refer: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices&ssr=false#qna --> --> If I install SSIS extension 0.3 (older version) the ADO.NET components and other toolbox items appear in project targetting SQL 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because with Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5 and SSIS extension 1.0/1.0.1, the SSIS projects that target SQL 2017 are broken.

Either an extension or a VS 2022 bug.

If I downgrade the SSIS extension to 0.3, all the toolbox items including ADO .NET source/destination components appears normally.

For more information https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices&ssr=false#qna

Answer (score 0):

I think the ADO.NET Source and ADO.NET Destination components are not available in SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) projects targeting SQL Server 2017. These components were introduced in later versions of SSIS and are not included in the toolbox by default for SQL Server 2017 projects.
Within the "Data Flow" tab, open the SSIS Toolbox (if it's not already open) by going to View > SSIS Toolbox.
In the SSIS Toolbox, scroll down and locate the "Sources" section.
Drag and drop the "OLE DB Source" component from the toolbox onto the design surface of the data flow task. (Just a workaround)

Comment: This is a bug introduced in the latest update of SSIS extension or may be VS 2022 update. For more information refer: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices&ssr=false#qna, --> If I install SSIS extension 0.3 (older version) the ADO.NET components and other toolbox items appear in project targetting  SQL 2017.